# Filesystem type on Solaris 5.10

Tags: filesystems, mount, solaris

How can I get the file system type for each device on Solaris 5.10?  I tried `mount` with no args but that only listed each mount point, similar to `df`.

Also, how can I find where a specific directory is mounted to, directly, without which of the mounting points is its superdirectory or grep?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're looking for is:

```
fstyp [-v] <device>
```

See the [manpage here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1462/fstyp-1m.html)

For the second part: If you change into directory in question you can do:

```
df .
```

Which will tell you the mountpoint and the corresponding device.

Comment: thanks.  any idea about the 2nd question?

Comment: @foampile Amended.

Answer (score 2):

`mount -v` includes the file system type in its more verbose output listing.

From a Solaris 10 system here:

```
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0 on / type ufs read/write/setuid/devices/intr/largefiles/logging/xattr/onerror=panic/dev=700040 on Tue May  1 11:33:55 2012
/devices on /devices type devfs read/write/setuid/devices/dev=4380000 on Tue May  1 11:33:43 2012
ctfs on /system/contract type ctfs read/write/setuid/devices/dev=43c0001 on Tue May  1 11:33:43 2012
proc on /proc type proc read/write/setuid/devices/dev=4400000 on Tue May  1 11:33:43 2012
mnttab on /etc/mnttab type mntfs read/write/setuid/devices/dev=4440001 on Tue May  1 11:33:43 2012
swap on /etc/svc/volatile type tmpfs read/write/setuid/devices/xattr/dev=4480001 on Tue May  1 11:33:43 2012
/dev/dsk/c1t0d0p0:boot on /boot type pcfs read/write/setuid/devices/nohidden/nofoldcase/dev=723050 on Tue May  1 11:33:54 2012
```